# Enabling GridView columns when GridView checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

in a GridView (ASP.NET/C#), I have a number of template fields - the 2 ones relevant to the question are 'checkbox1' and 'quantity'. The checkbox starts off as unticked for every row, and the quantity starts off as disabled for every row. But when the user ticks one of the rows checkboxes, I need a piece of JavaScript or something to check if the relevant rows checkbox is checked, and if so enable to the rows quantity textbox.

How do I do this?

Comment: You want to do this without doing a postback?

Comment: Ideally, yes. Posting back each time the box is selected would be a bit inelegant.

Comment: I agree. Posting back would be the easiest way, but not the fastest.(or most elegant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you start with your quantity disabled. I am assuming it is a TextBox:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="quantity" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Add this piece of javascript on your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ChangeQuantityEnable(id, enable) {
        document.getElementById(id).disabled = !enable;
    }

</script>
```

Then in the RowDataBound event handler for your gridview, add

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("checkbox1");
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("quantity");

    chk.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("ChangeQuantityEnable('{0}', this.checked);", txt.ClientID);
}
```

Comment: Worked absolutely perfect. Thanks very much!